# Oracle 11g directory objects to remote path

Tags: oracle, oracle10g, oracle11g

We're in the process of migrating over a system from Oracle 10G (windows 2003 32 bit) to 11G (on windows 2008 R2 64bit), where currently, our backup process consist a directory object that points to a remote (unc) path on our storage box so that we don't have to perform the expdp locally, and then move the file, which seems to work without issue, however on our new windows 2008 box with 11G, I can create the directory object and test it through the EM console, however whenever I try to run my import, I get the following:

```
Connected to: Oracle Database 11g Release 11.2.0.2.0 - 64bit ProductionWith the Automatic
Storage Management option
ORA-39002: invalid operation
ORA-39070: Unable to open the log file.
ORA-29283: invalid file operation
ORA-06512: at "SYS.UTL_FILE", line 536
ORA-29283: invalid file operation
```

Any ideas??  Just trying to test with metadata_only right now to troubleshoot this, but still no luck.

```
E:\>impdp xxxxx/xxxxx@prod CONTENT=METADATA_ONLY directory=Restoreloc dumpfile=XXXXX_
MAY172011.DMP logfile=XXXXXIMPDP.log exclude=grant
```

Answer (score 1):

Ensure that the oracle process has write access to the directory.

or

You have to manually create directory in specified path then try your operation.
Check this [post](http://www.orafaq.com/forum/mv/msg/71697/200733/0/#msg_200733).

Comment: Thank you for the response.  I believe your first comment it what will allow this to work, however any time I've tried to change the "logon" credentials through my windows service properties to an Admin user, the database service no longer starts... it seems as though the service will only run as "Local system account", regardless of what network admin account I use.  How else can I troubleshoot this through a Windows environment?